# how to view Netbeans 8.2 java library coding

Tags: java, netbeans

I had install netbeans 8.2 version the problem is for example imagine that we have cord like
String name = "thilina";
when I press ctrl+ mouse click on String word it will view a String class but, codes in side the functions not showing instead of code it shows [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8Ez6.jpg)// compiled code like fallowing image

Comment: Did you download SDK sources?

Comment: you mean this documents ?https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jdk8-doc-downloads-2133158.html

Comment: @Antoniossss A JDK includes its source in **src.zip** so there is no need for a further download. Perhaps you are thinking of the download of the Javadocs for the JDK?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the **Sources** for your JDK 8 entry in NetBeans:

- Select **Tools > Java Platforms** to open the **Java Platform Manager** window, then select the entry in the **Platforms** panel for **JDK 1.8**.
- Click the **Sources** tab, then click the **Add JAR/folder...** button.
- Navigate to your installation directory for JDK 8, select the file named **src.zip**, then click the **Add JAR/Folder** button.
- This should create an entry in the **Platform Sources** panel:

  [image: Java Platform Manager]
- Click the **Close** button to close the **Java Platform Manager** window.

Now if you press **ctrl + Mouse click** on `String` in your source you should see the source code for **String.java**.